# How to add CheckBoxes to a ComboBox?

Tags: checkbox, combobox, codenameone

I want to create a ComboBox having Checkboxes as children using Codename one.

**I am not using the UIBuilder**

For reusability I created a Container having three Checkboxes in it:

```
OverviewCheckBoxContainer
 - Checkbox1
 - Checkbox2
 - Checkbox3
```

and this works already.

As it takes too much space on the screen, I now tried to add the CheckBoxContainer into a Combobox, like this:

```
ComboBox
 - OverviewCheckBoxCont
    -...
```

but it does not work, the ComboBox contains a single entry only  and it's not a checkbox, but a text:

```
OverviewCheckBoxCont[x=...
```

(cannot see further on the screen)

How can I solve this issue, so there is a dropdown menu containing the three Checkboxes, that toggle onClick?

ps:

In the main form I added the CheckBoxesComboBox instead of the CheckBoxesCont:

```
 this.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, checkBoxesComboBox)
```

instead of

```
 this.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, checkBoxesCont)
```

Answer (score 2):

1.You can use simple combobox as shown below

```
 ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
 findComboBox().setModel(new DefaultListModel(al));
```

2.And to add checkbox in combobox , you have to customize the combobox

3.Instead  of customizing combobox,  You can use button which shows and hides OverviewCheckBoxContainer which contains list of checkboxs

See this for customizing the ComboBox with the generic list cell renderer: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/components.html#_combobox

The problem with using checkboxes in a combo is that you would assume they would all appear in the combo as a set and the combo wasn't designed to do that. I would instead just use a `Button` and show a dialog with a set of checkboxes then set the text of the `Button` to match the result. You can style the button to look like a `ComboBox` if that is your preference.

Comment: Updated answer with some additional insight

Comment: I have to admit that I don't really know how to do the thing with the button.  In the center of the form there already is a custom list and the button needs to be in the north of the Borderlayout. Adding the checkboxes 'onClick' results in not depicting them. (I called the repaint method though).
And remember: **I don't use the UIBuilder - __findComboBox__ does not work..**
EDIT: They are depicted, but not visible for the user

Comment: And I would really want to avoid a Dialog

Comment: @tizbn the overviewCheckBoxCont(tainer) http://pastebin.com/2wMYe95j the overviewContainer http://pastebin.com/dxpivprM containing the checkboxcontainer. As it is now, the checkboxes are only depicted north of a custom list (which you dont need to care about for now).